# Implications of John Searle's distinction between brute facts and social facts?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

According to John Searle, there is a difference between "brute facts" and "social facts." How does this view impact educational theory and practice?

Comment: Does your title represent your question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. This looks like a test/HW question, we answer those if some research effort is shown and specific difficulty identified. General description of Searle's view on "construction of social reality" can be found [here](http://www.angelfire.com/md2/timewarp/searle.html).

Comment: Brute facts: Red light has a wavelength of 700–635 nm and green light  560–520 nm. A Martian physicist would agree with us about that. Social facts: Red light means stop, green light means go. A Martian physicists would not have any idea of that without studying the social customs and laws on earth. Now: What do you mean by the impact of this distinction on education theory and practice?